# How to disable running applications in unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, autohide

There are some pinned application in launcher, but if I run an unpinned application from the dash then I want to stop it from appearing in the launcher.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by disable?

Comment: please ,improve your question and do you mean remove from unity luncher ?

Comment: This is by design. My research indicates that there is no functionality via dconf editor, nor tweak tool that will blacklist an application from showing on the launcher when it is running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to quit a running application from the launcher, right-click on that icon and select `Quit`.

If you want to remove a pinned application from the launcher, right-click on that icon and select `Unlock from Launcher`.

**Update:**

I'm not aware of being able to not display unpinned/running applications. However, you can auto-hide the launcher so that you don't have to see them. Go to System Settings/Appearance/Behavior and enable auto-hiding.

Comment: When I read the question before reading your answer to it, I naively assumed that Sanjay meant to "disable using the Launcher for running applications". Clearly some additional clarification of the question is necessary, and maybe you will need to edit your answer afterwards. Rather than cast the final close vote to close the question as unclear, I am waiting to see if this problem will sort itself out, and if it does sort itself out I will vote to reopen the question if necessary. Please ping me in chat to update me about this issue if necessary.

Comment: @heynnema  Question is updated.